# I'm on Bluehost VPS and it randomly redirects me to another customers site

Tags: linux, apache, vps, redirect, bluehost

After days of searching Google and trying other peoples fixes, I can't seem to get around the problem.

I have my site hosted on Bluehost, and a few weeks ago I switched to their VPS service. It has apache(And I believe it's run on Linux).

I'm new to this whole apache, server, vps stuff, so bear with me.

Now after switching to VPS, at complete random times, for a minute or two, my web site gets redirected to another bluehost customer. I only found out they are another customer because there was a bluehost logo on their site, and their site is still under mid way construction. This seems to happen like every ten minutes, and it always goes to the same person's web site. Further, my URL is still at the top, but it displays their web site.

Also, if I try to go to anther page other than my index.php while this is happening, it says files not found on apache server. So it leads me to believe that the server starts to look in other directories for the files.

Bluehost doesn't know what is going on. So I need help if any of you can!

My site is all PHP and HTML. Uses MYSQL. Uses WHM(webhost manager), and I couldn't find any problems in the WHM settings either...
Checked my .htaccess, httpd.conf, index.php and other php files I have when a user hits my home page.
Checked a name records, ip addresses, all that stuff.

Thanks!

Edit: Another thing I noticed. Sometime's when I load my site and this kind of stuff is happening, it loads half the images, and the other half wont load. So it seems it gets confused at random on where to look for the files.

Further, FTP access gets denied as well! Seems the server completely changes itself to another server and locks me out.

Comment: you are going to have to contact bluehost and ask them What is going on.  It is possible there is an ip or mapping conflict or something in their routing that is sending you to the wrong place.

Comment: It seems to me that Bluehost is using some kind of software to create multiple VPS on a shared server and has it set up incorrectly. But that's just a theory :( - However, they did tell me it's a shared server. So that part is true.

Comment: Contact your hosting provider for support. This is almost certainly an issue with their system configuration.

Comment: Well a VPS is by definition on a shared host, but there are lots of different ways to do it, and add marketing in there to further muddy the distinctions.  It is an actual image, or something using jails/ zones/containers (I don't know how bluehost does it)  To further diagnose ip issues. if you get console/shell access do and ifconfig, is your public IP listed as the ip on any interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what happened. My domain was hosted with Yahoo and some how yahoo was having issues pointing my domain to my bluehost server's hosted files!

Switched my domain to bluehost. Don't ask my why I had my domain with Yahoo(it's a long story)

So for any one having issues like this, I suggest making sure you have files and domain with same host.